# MAC bash shell - store output from command

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I have the following script.

```
python3_path = $(which python3)
echo "Python 3 path: "
echo $python3_path
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
./seed.sh: line 123: python3_path: command not found
Python 3 path:
```

I'm not sure why python3_path is empty here.

Comment: Remove the spaces around `=`.

Answer (score 2):

bash is finicky.
Do not put spaces around `=` when assigning variables.

Try this instead:

```
python3_path=$(which python3)
echo "Python 3 path: "
echo $python3_path
```

or you could also do it this way:

```
python3_path=$(which python3)
echo "Python 3 path: $python3_path"
```

or this way is even shorter:

```
echo "Python 3 path: $(which python3)"
```